# Android button text and HTML Superscript and Subscript

Tags: java, android, html, xml

I am trying to insert superscript and subscript text into android button text.
I have tried by giving the following in strings.xml file

```
<string name="NAME"><![CDATA[<sup><small>-1</small></sup>]]></string>
```

And in the MainActivity.java file,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    Button NAME = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
    NAME.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.NAME)));
}
```

But i am unable to succeed.

Query:

- Is there any way to specify it in "strings.xml" file itself without using setText in code ?

Comment: use R.string.NAME instead of R.string.iHyperbolic

Comment: your calling R.string.iHyperbolic please clear string name

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** 
You are fetching wrong value.

**Solution:**
use `R.string.NAME` instead of `R.string.iHyperbolic`

your `NAME` carries the html string and not `iHyperbolic`.

> Is there any way to specify it in "strings.xml" file itself without
>   using setText in code ?

AFAIK, You will have to use setText() to set the html string after it is processed by Html class. Cause Html class processes HTML strings into displayable styled text.And if you wish to display this Html styled text on a widget then you will have to use setText().

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing:

```
<sup><small>-1</small></sup>
```

try writing:

```
<sup>-1</sup>
```

Hope helps :)

Comment: could you please tell what difference that would make? Cause AFAIK, <small> will apply small font to superscript or subscript.

Comment: @RiteshGune, it can make a difference, because `sup` may apply font size reduction to its content, and if it is already reduced due to `small`, you get double reduction.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, I didn't see <sup> reducing font size on its own as far as its use in android is concerned. It just positions the text. I would be happy to go through any doc supporting your statement, If you could provide :)

Comment: I changed it as with only "sup" tag.  But when i start the application, it exits with "Unfortunately my app has closed" error messages.

Comment: @RiteshGune, sorry, my comment was too hasty. Was thinking in terms of HTML.

Comment: @RiteshGune: Still the error persists.. Is my MainActivity.java file is correct ?  Because, i am unable to set the button text..